# How do I input an array of keys into a map, and get out an array of values corresponding to those keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

Basically, say I have a **Map < Integer, String> {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 4 -> "d"}** theMap,

And I have an an **ArrayList < Integer> {1,2,3}** someKeys

How do I do something like:

```
ArrayList<String> someValues = theMap.get(someKeys);
```

And have the contents of someValues be {"a", "b", null}

Seems like such an easy problem, but I've spent the last half hour searching, and can't find anything. There's gotta be a better way to do it than

```
for(int i = 0; i<someKeys.size(); i++
{
    someValues.add(theMap.get(someKeys.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you like this solution ?

Comment: Because that's brute forcing it. Combining tables like this is easy in SQL

Comment: SQL will search into the index (if any) just like you will check into the key entries in the map ... so yes, you can speak of _bruteforce_ but this is simply iterating.

Comment: The fact is that, based on how the map is structured internally, and why, i would say that what you do there (the iteration) is exactly how it should be done, as the map is a lookup, so you would have to retrieve the value to check if it exists. If there where to be a built in function doing this for you, it would likely work with iterating the map as well. And comparisons with SQL is of course moot in any case as that is a query language working on indexed tables, whereas the "map" in this case is implemented in a semi-compiled executable and is not a table...

Comment: Is there really no Collections function or built-in function to HashMap that takes a list of keys, inserts it into a map, and returns a list of objects? That seems like a huge oversight.

Comment: Not really, because of what the hashmap is (hash based lookup) but on the other hand, like i said, you wrote one in your original example. That is a fine example of such a function, because the way the map works it is what would need to be done anyhow. So if there was a built in facility in Collections to do it, it would be a variant of what you did most likely.

Comment: Using a SortedMap should improved the search drasticly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream`s :

```
List<String> values = someKeys.stream()
                              .map(k->theMap.get(k))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will add nulls for keys that don't appear in the `Map`, which you can eliminate with an additional filtering step :

```
List<String> values = someKeys.stream()
                              .map(k->theMap.get(k))
                              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<String> values = someKeys.stream()
                              .filter(k->theMap.containsKey(k))
                              .map(k->theMap.get(k))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I found that more complicated (complexe) in this case using Stream, don't you ?

Comment: So, there isn't a pre-baked Collections function that will combine the keyList with the map and produce a valueList?

Comment: @AxelH It's a matter of taste. If you want to avoid an explicit loop (and the explicit List creation), you can used Streams.

Comment: On the other hand, the stream will reduce to iteration anyway i think... Only it does it by the anonymous lambda k, in this case. But like stated, matter of taste.

Comment: @Eran, and what about performance in this case ? Just asking, I only used Stream here and there...

Comment: @AxelH You should only worry about performance when you encounter a performance problem. Other than that, you'll have to run a benchmark to compare performance.

Comment: @Eran, since OP is comparing his request to SQL, I suppose this will work with a lot of data so I am wondering what will be the impact in time and memory. I hate this sentence `worry about performance when you encounter a performance problem` to be honnest ;) Because I know there won't be much problem with a Map, will test with Stream later

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you can not use java 8 and altering the map is not an issue then invoke the method **retainAll()** in the **keySet** of the map :)

```
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(1, "A");
    myMap.put(2, "A");
    myMap.put(4, "A");
    List<Integer> myKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    myKeys.add(1);
    myKeys.add(2);
    myKeys.add(3);
    myMap.keySet().retainAll(myKeys);
    System.out.println("filtered" + myMap);
```

Comment: Note that the question is about producing a "new" ArrayList<String> of the resulting vals. Also, i interpret that as not desroying the map...